# What is the most expensive Bitcoin purchase ever made?

Tags: transactions, history, merchants

Relying only on publicly disclosed data, what is the most expensive Bitcoin purchase that has ever occurred?

"Expensive" can be determined either by:

1. Highest purchase price in Bitcoins
2. Highest fiat value equivalent at the time

Comment: Do you count using Bitcoin to buy fiat currency?

Comment: @NickODell I had not thought of that (it is not what I had in mind) but am interested in that answer too. Was it the US Marshalls auction?

Comment: related: [What is the largest transaction by value to date for bitcoin currency?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3287/5406)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it was the selling of dice gamling site SatoshiDice in 2013, according to the former owner it was sold for 126,315 BTC which was equivalent to ~$11,5 Million at that time.

More details can be found here: 
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=101902.msg2751536#msg2751536

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the greatest amount of bitcoin spent,  the "bitcoin pizza" comes to mind. At a whopping 10k BTC spent.

[Pizza for bitcoins? (bitcointalk.org)](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=137.0)

Answer (score -2):

It could also be in the beginning when Satoshi probably sold a lot of bitcoins at cheap to his close friends.

Comment: Please provide evidence or support for your answer. As it is, it seems to be completely speculative.